# ReactMultiSelectCheckboxes can not set placeholder

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

ReactMultiSelectCheckboxes

I can not set a placeholder it shows its default label like select...
How can I set it?

Following is my code

```
<ReactMultiSelectCheckboxes 
    options={coursedropdown.course} 
    name="courses" 
    onChange={ e => onCourseChange(e) }  
    placeholder="Select Course"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the usage of [react-multiselect-checkboxes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-multiselect-checkboxes),

you should use `placeholderButtonLabel` instead of `placeholder`.

Your code should be...

```
<ReactMultiSelectCheckboxes 
    options={coursedropdown.course} 
    name="courses" 
    onChange={ e => onCourseChange(e) }  
    placeholderButtonLabel="Select Course"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use property

```
placeholderButtonLabel=""
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `placeholderButtonLabel` instead of the `placeholder`.

[Please check this URL for more usage of](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-multiselect-checkboxes) `ReactMultiSelectCheckboxes`.